# Sync data from coredata with custom REST API when internet connection lost?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Hi all I'm working with a developer to build a swift iOS app that uses coredata and connects to a custom REST API. We've come up with the usecase where the user will update their settings in the app, but before it saves to the API the internet connection is lost.

What I'm wanting to know is, what is the best way to ensure that the data that is input locally is saved to ensure it is not lost when the internet connection is lost?

I'm thinking a simple solution could be to use a couple of timestamp fields on the local model. 1 for when the local model is updated within the app and then another when the model is saved up to the API. This way the app can check if the data has been synced with the API or not if the local timestamp is less then or greater than the API timestamp.

Is this a good approach or are there already standard libraries or techniques used in this usecase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record a transaction log when you are offline.  You can capture that through the `NSManagedObjectContext` API, asking it for `updatedObjects`, `insertedObjects`, and `deletedObjects`.

Then when you get online you play back the transaction log against the server.